# Webpack relative vs absolute path

Tags: javascript, webpack, require, node-modules

```
src
|
+-- action.js
|
+-- dir1
       |
       +--dir2
            |
            +--dir3
                 |
                 +--file.js
```

To import `action.js` from `file.js`, I need to do `require('../../../action')`.

Is it a good idea to configure webpack to use `src` as the root, and import with `require('action')`?

This avoids the need to check how many `../` are needed to import a module in a file in a deeply nested folder.

But we won't be able to tell if `action` is from `node_modules` or `src`.

Is there a better alternative that solves both of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) example has the entry point about 4 levels deep. I would suggest focusing on making your folder structure less deep if ../../../ is cumbersome. About node modules. You don't need ../, because require('some-module') will automatically look up the correct node module.

Comment: I meant if we set `src` as root and `require('someModule')`, the developers won't be able to tell immediately if `someModule` is in `node_modules` or within `src`.

Comment: But the developers will know because regular file reverences will always start have some sort of prefix, even if it is in the same folder. (Example require('./someModule')). Whereas node modules always have just their name like this. require('someModule'), right?

Comment: Yes...but if I set `src` as root and use absolute path then it'd no longer be the case.